# Why do colours change in water

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life

I was doing my swimming rounds, when it turned dark, so the pool management turned on the lights. The lights were actually yellow in colour, but they appeared green if I moved far away from them underwater(6 to 7m). They looked yellow above water. Someone please explain this.

Comment: What color are the walls and the floor of the swimming pool?

Comment: Blue in varying shades.

Answer (score 3):

Water absorbs light, especially at the red end of the spectrum. Red appears to be black under just a few meters of water.

Up close to the light, you see all the colors the light emits.

A few meters away, you see the bluer and greener colors only.

Comment: But would this really change the yellow (even orange, if the lights were HPS lamps) to green through mere 6 meters? From my calculations (using 1997 Pope and Fry water absorbance from [here](https://omlc.org/spectra/water/abs/index.html)), pure HPS lamp spectrum (digitized from [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:High_Pressure_Sodium_Lamp_Spectrum.jpg)) yields sRGB value of `#ff7c00`, while behind 7 meters of water it becomes `#ffb73a`, which is not green at all.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? It is very vague.